# Extract email HTML Element

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape a page and there is a point I am stuck at. Here's first the HTML part of the whole HTML page

```html
<article class="mod mod-Treffer" data-teilnehmerid="122085958708">
   
   <div data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;: &quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Trefferliste Eintrag zur Detailseite&quot;, &quot;id&quot;: &quot;122085958708&quot;, &quot;synchron&quot;: true}" data-realid="2aeca1d2-2bc5-4070-ac4d-e16b10badca5" data-tnid="122085958708" target="_self">
    
  <div class="mod-hervorhebung">
 <p class="mod-hervorhebung--partnerHervorhebung" data-hervorhebungsstufe="3">Silber Partner</p>

 

 
</div>
  
   <picture class="trefferlisten_logo">
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://ies.v4all.de/0122/GS/0122/5/8335/49428335_310x190.png">
  
  <img alt="" data-lazy-src="https://ies.v4all.de/0122/GS/0122/5/8335/49428335_310x190.png" src="https://ies.v4all.de/0122/GS/0122/5/8335/49428335_310x190.png">
 </picture>
  
  <h2 data-wipe-name="Titel">A &amp; S Billing Pflege-Service GmbH</h2>
  <p class="d-inline-block mod-Treffer--besteBranche">Ambulante Pflegedienste</p>
  
   
   <div class="mod mod-Stars mod-Stars--" title="2.9/5" data-float="2,9">

  <span class="mod-Stars__text" style="width: 58.000001907348632812500%;">2.9</span>

 </div>
   <span>2.9</span>
   <span>(8)</span>
  
 
  
  <address class="mod mod-AdresseKompakt">
  <p data-wipe-name="Adresse">
   Kirchenberg&nbsp;2‑4, 
   <span class="nobr">
    90482
    Nürnberg
   </span>
   (Mögeldorf)
   
  </p>

  <p class="mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber" data-hochgestellt-position="end" data-wipe-name="Kontaktdaten">(0911) 60 00 99 77</p>

 </address>
  
 
   </div>
   
    <div class="aktionsleiste_kompakt">
  
 <div class="mod-gsSlider mod-gsSlider--noneOnWhite">
  <span class="mod-gsSlider__arrow mod-gsSlider__arrow--arrow" data-direction="left" data-show="false" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste: Aktionleiste-button-links&quot;}"></span>
  <span class="mod-gsSlider__arrow mod-gsSlider__arrow--arrow" data-direction="right" data-show="false" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste: Aktionleiste-button-rechts&quot;}"></span>
  <div class="mod-gsSlider__slider" data-initialized="true">
   
   
   
   
   
   
    
  
   <a class="contains-icon-homepage gs-btn" target="_blank" rel=" noopener" href="http://www.as-billing.de" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Webseite-Button&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-isneededpromise="false">Webseite</a>
   
  

  
 
   
    
  
   <a class="contains-icon-email gs-btn" href="mailto:info@as-billing.de?subject=Anfrage%20%C3%BCber%20Gelbe%20Seiten" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Email-Button&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-isneededpromise="false">E-Mail</a>
   
  

  
 
   
    
  
   
   <span class="contains-icon-route_finden gs-btn" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Navigation-Button&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-parameters="{&quot;partner&quot;: &quot;googlemaps&quot;, &quot;searchquery&quot;: &quot;A%20%26%20S%20Billing%20Pflege-Service%20GmbH%20Kirchenberg%202-4%2090482%20N%C3%BCrnberg&quot;}" data-target="_blank">Route</span>
  

  
 
   
    
  
   
   <span class="contains-icon-details gs-btn" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Actionbutton Mehr Details&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-parameters="{&quot;partner&quot;: &quot;gs&quot;, &quot;realId&quot;: &quot;2aeca1d2-2bc5-4070-ac4d-e16b10badca5&quot;, &quot;tnId&quot;: &quot;122085958708&quot;}">Mehr Details</span>
  

  
 
   
   
  </div>
 </div>

 </div>
   
   
   
   
  </article>
```

I first used these lines

```
Dim post As Object

Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".mod-Treffer")

For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("Address")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(1).innerText

'I am stuck with extracting the email
'HERE
Next i
```

Moreover, sometimes the post object doesn't have the email inforrmation so I need to extract only if found.

That's the code till now

```
    Const sURL As String = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/Ambulante%20Pflegedienste/Bundesweit"
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As HTMLDocument

Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

With http
    .Open "Get", sURL, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Dim post As Object

Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".mod-Treffer")

Dim i As Long, r As Long
Range("A1").Resize(1, 3).Value = Array("Title", "Phone", "Email")
r = 2

For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
Cells(r, 1).Value = post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innerText
Cells(r, 2).Value = post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("Address")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(1).innerText


Next i
```

Here's a snapshot of the email part
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original question:**

In this case I would use an attribute = value selector with contains operator to target the `href` attribute by the string `mailto`. Add css selector: `[href*=mailto]`

If you use `querySelectorAll("[href*=mailto]")` you can test if the `.Length` property is greater than 0 or use `querySelector` and test `if Not querySelector("[href*=mailto]") Is Nothing`.

If you set to a variable

```
Dim ele As Object

Set ele = html.document.querySelector("[href*=mailto]")
If Not ele Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print ele.href  'do something with the href to parse out email
End If
```

---

**Updated question:**

For the updated question I would transfer current node's, in nodeList, `outerHTML` into a surrogate `HTMLDocument` variable so I can leverage `querySelector` method again. I would target email by class.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetListingInfo()

    Const URL As String = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/Ambulante%20Pflegedienste/Bundesweit"
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "Get", URL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim post As Object, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".mod-Treffer")
    Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim i As Long, emailNode As Object

    With ActiveSheet

        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 3).Value = Array("Title", "Phone", "Email")

        For i = 0 To post.Length - 1

            html2.body.innerHTML = post.Item(i).outerHTML

            .Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = html2.querySelector("h2").innerText
            .Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = html2.querySelector(".mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber").innerText

            Set emailNode = html2.querySelector(".contains-icon-email")

            If Not emailNode Is Nothing Then .Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = Replace$(emailNode.href, "mailto:", vbNullString)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, I would use it inside loop of post object I referred to so I changed your line to `Set ele = post.Item(i).querySelector("[href*=mailto]")` but this throws an error. What is the fault?. I have updated and put the code till now.

Comment: you can't  use querySelector except on document in vba

Comment: How many emails are you expecting to retrieve? You would use querySelectorAll to gather all mailto href nodes instead and loop that extracting href

Comment: I don't see any emails on the url you have now added to question. Search doesn't return any results either. Is there an url where I can see Title", "Phone", "Email" ?

Comment: I have updated the thread and put a snapshot. I expect 41 emails out of 50 articles.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just edited this part `Replace(Split(emailNode.href, "?")(0), "mailto:", "")`. Last question: using two HTMLDocument make the code slower or didn't affect?!!

Comment: Use replace. I had also edited my answer for that. See above.

Comment: You won't notice any speed issue with using two HTMLDocument. You get access to faster css selectors by using querySelector though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
I could figure it out using these lines

```
    If InStr(post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(1).href, "mailto:") Then
    Debug.Print Split(Split(post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(1).href, "mailto:")(1), "?")(0)
End If
```

But I welcome any other suggestions to improve and learn more.
* After testing, I encountered an error if the email not found within the element. How to avoid the error? I can use `On Error Resume Next`. But I have a desire to handle the error instead of skipping it.

** Edit:
I could solve the second point by using this structure

```
    Dim emailObj As Object

Set emailObj = post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(1)
If Not emailObj Is Nothing Then
 If InStr(post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(1).href, "mailto:") Then
    Debug.Print Split(Split(post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(1).href, "mailto:")(1), "?")(0)
End If
```

> > The code works but sometimes the email is not grabbed correctly .. that is because of this line

```
Set emailObj = post.Item(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(1)
```

Sometimes the object is not assigned to 1. So my last question: how can I get the email data regardless of the assigned number?

Inside the loop, I tried this line and played around with no use

```
Set aNodeList = post.Item(i).querySelectorAll(".contains-icon-email")(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<article class="mod mod-Treffer" data-teilnehmerid="122085958708">
            
            <div data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;: &quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Trefferliste Eintrag zur Detailseite&quot;, &quot;id&quot;: &quot;122085958708&quot;, &quot;synchron&quot;: true}" data-realid="2aeca1d2-2bc5-4070-ac4d-e16b10badca5" data-tnid="122085958708" target="_self">
                
        <div class="mod-hervorhebung">
    <p class="mod-hervorhebung--partnerHervorhebung" data-hervorhebungsstufe="3">Silber Partner</p>

    

    
</div>
        
            <picture class="trefferlisten_logo">
        <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="https://ies.v4all.de/0122/GS/0122/5/8335/49428335_310x190.png">
        
        <img alt="" data-lazy-src="https://ies.v4all.de/0122/GS/0122/5/8335/49428335_310x190.png" src="https://ies.v4all.de/0122/GS/0122/5/8335/49428335_310x190.png">
    </picture>
        
        <h2 data-wipe-name="Titel">A &amp; S Billing Pflege-Service GmbH</h2>
        <p class="d-inline-block mod-Treffer--besteBranche">Ambulante Pflegedienste</p>
        
            
            <div class="mod mod-Stars mod-Stars--" title="2.9/5" data-float="2,9">

        <span class="mod-Stars__text" style="width: 58.000001907348632812500%;">2.9</span>

    </div>
            <span>2.9</span>
            <span>(8)</span>
        
    
        
        <address class="mod mod-AdresseKompakt">
        <p data-wipe-name="Adresse">
            Kirchenberg&nbsp;2‑4, 
            <span class="nobr">
                90482
                Nürnberg
            </span>
            (Mögeldorf)
            
        </p>

        <p class="mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber" data-hochgestellt-position="end" data-wipe-name="Kontaktdaten">(0911) 60 00 99 77</p>

    </address>
        
    
            </div>
            
                <div class="aktionsleiste_kompakt">
        
    <div class="mod-gsSlider mod-gsSlider--noneOnWhite">
        <span class="mod-gsSlider__arrow mod-gsSlider__arrow--arrow" data-direction="left" data-show="false" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste: Aktionleiste-button-links&quot;}"></span>
        <span class="mod-gsSlider__arrow mod-gsSlider__arrow--arrow" data-direction="right" data-show="false" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste: Aktionleiste-button-rechts&quot;}"></span>
        <div class="mod-gsSlider__slider" data-initialized="true">
            
            
            
            
            
            
                
        
            <a class="contains-icon-homepage gs-btn" target="_blank" rel=" noopener" href="http://www.as-billing.de" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Webseite-Button&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-isneededpromise="false">Webseite</a>
            
        

        
    
            
                
        
            <a class="contains-icon-email gs-btn" href="mailto:info@as-billing.de?subject=Anfrage%20%C3%BCber%20Gelbe%20Seiten" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Email-Button&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-isneededpromise="false">E-Mail</a>
            
        

        
    
            
                
        
            
            <span class="contains-icon-route_finden gs-btn" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Navigation-Button&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-parameters="{&quot;partner&quot;: &quot;googlemaps&quot;, &quot;searchquery&quot;: &quot;A%20%26%20S%20Billing%20Pflege-Service%20GmbH%20Kirchenberg%202-4%2090482%20N%C3%BCrnberg&quot;}" data-target="_blank">Route</span>
        

        
    
            
                
        
            
            <span class="contains-icon-details gs-btn" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Actionbutton Mehr Details&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;122085958708&quot;}" data-parameters="{&quot;partner&quot;: &quot;gs&quot;, &quot;realId&quot;: &quot;2aeca1d2-2bc5-4070-ac4d-e16b10badca5&quot;, &quot;tnId&quot;: &quot;122085958708&quot;}">Mehr Details</span>
        

        
    
            
            
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
            
            
            
            
        </article>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).